# How to read and insert an image in a Word document?

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a skeleton Word document in .docx format that includes an image of my signature.  I want to update the document using Python. This works well but the signature image disappears when I do this. How can I read the image from the file and then insert it somewhere? I tried

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document('test.docx')
inline_shapes = doc.inline_shapes
for inline_shape in inline_shapes:
    ....
```

But inline_shapes is empty.

I am using python-docx version '0.8.11'.

Comment: Could your signature be a floating shape? This might explain why you're not seeing it in the inline_shapes list...

Comment: @Jonathan How can I look for floating shapes?

Comment: "At the time of writing, python-docx only supports inline pictures. " from https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html